Easier way to route audio output to audio interface channels
I have a (class compliant) 4-channel audio interface and I'd like to route the audio output to its channels. I know I can use the MIDI Setup tool for this but it's very inconvenient for frequent use. On Linux I have (by default) two output devices for two stereo lines and I can quickly switch between speakers and headphones for example.
Can I accomplish this on macOS?

A workaround is to create an aggregate device (with the Audio MIDI tool) of just the audio interface with the specific channels. The caveat is that the output volume is controlled with the original device.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
